# Java 8: Convert 2 Lists into List of Map

Tags: java, java-stream

What I have: (2 lists)

```
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<String[]> values = Arrays.asList("a,aa,aaa".split(","), "b,bb,bbb".split(","));
```

What I'm trying to get: (list of map)

```
[
    {"1": "a", "2": "aa", "3": "aaa"},
    {"1": "b", "2": "bb", "3": "bbb"}
]
```

Java 7 Solution:

```
List<Map<String,String>> list = new LinkedList<Map<String,String>>();
for(String[] vs: values) {
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        map.put(keys.get(i), vs[i]);
    }
    list.add(map);
}
```

I'm learning Java 8 and steam. I wonder if it's possible to do it cleaner.

Comment: Note that sometimes more code with comments can be a lot easier to read and understand than a super compact stream solution. So while it definitely is good for learning purpose, you should ask yourself if you should use such code in a real project with other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to iterate over `values` and then iterate over the indexes of each array, matching them to the corresponding index in `keys`:

```
List<Map<String, String>> maps = values.stream()
        .map(a -> IntStream.range(0, keys.size())
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(keys::get, i -> a[i])))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The intermediate boxing is unfortunately necessary in order to use the `toMap()` collector. If you want to avoid the overhead of boxed indexing, you can define a custom collector in the inner stream:

```
IntStream.range(0, keys.size())
    .collect(HashMap<String, String>::new,
        (m, i) -> m.put(keys.get(i), a[i]),
        HashMap::putAll)
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below two ways to achieve this using java 8 stream:

List values =Arrays.asList("a,aa,aaa".split(","), "b,bb,bbb".split(","));

```
      List<Map<String, String>> maps= values.stream().map(l-> IntStream.range(0, l.length).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i-> String.valueOf(i+1), j-> l[j]))).collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println("Printing list of map using boxed"+ maps);

      List<Map<String, String>> maps2= values.stream().map(l-> IntStream.range(0, l.length).mapToObj(a-> Integer.valueOf(a)).collect(Collectors.toMap(i-> String.valueOf(i+1), j-> l[j]))).collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println("Printing list of map using maptoObject"+ maps2);
```